# Bash auto completion when similar file names

Tags: bash, terminal, autocomplete

I have `WSL2` installed.

Suppose that I have the following folder structure:

```
/mnt/c

   -- Documents and Settings

   -- Program Files

   -- Program Files (x86)
```

If I type in `cd Docum` and then press `tab`, Bash will autocomplete it to `cd Documents\ and\ Settings`, which is what I want.

However, if I type in `cd Prog` and then press tab, Bash will autocomplete to `cd Program`. The reason is because there are two folders which have the same starting, and Bash doesn't know which one to go to.

If I press tab again, I can see the following in my terminal:

```
user@pc: /mnt/c
$ cd Program
Program Files/       Program Files (x86)/
```

The matches are printed. I do not want this. I want to have the following:

1. When I type `cd Prog`, it will first autofill to `cd Program\ Files`

2. If I press `tab` again, then it will autofill to `cd Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/`

I know this can be done manually by typing in `cd Program\`  (notice the space at the end), and then pressing `tab` to get #1 done, but I want to know if this can be done automatically.

You can see below that this is the default behavior in `Windows PowerShell`
[image]

Comment: You say it gets to `Program`, not `Program Files`. Is there another directory in there, that also has a name starting with `Program`?

Comment: There is a ProgramData but I guess I forgot to mention that

Comment: Please edit question to make it clear.